# Log functions referring to an entity in the symbol table. Is that possible?

Tags: php

You have a variable:

$a = 0;

And this variable is passed by reference like crazy.

How do you log or gain all functions and methods that have been working on this variable?

Comment: have you tried xdebug and webgrind? it can show all functions and variables after execution

Comment: :-) ... I know XDebug. It lists traces and stacks ... but not referring to an entry in the symbol table ... at least not as far as I know ... you're welcome to tell me something I don't know.

Comment: Check [WebGrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) it can give complete information about all used variables, includes, classes. Pretty cool I think.

Comment: yet again, WebGrind cannot give you entry point of the variable on code but maybe you can find something useful in webgrind

Answer (score 1):

You can use xdebug to do reference counting (http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) but I don't think there is a way to determine where those references were created.  I think you'd have to write your own PHP module to get that information.